# Крестики и нолики (упрощенное) на заданном поле

Tags: python

```
def Победитель(x):
    for ei in ['X', 'O']:
        строка=x[O][O]==x[1][O]==x[2][O] or x[O][1]==x[1][1]==x[2][1] or x[O][2]==x[1][2]==x[2][2]
        столбец=x[O][O]==x[O][1]==x[O][2] or ei==x[1][O]==x[1][1]==x[1][2] or ei==x[2][O]==x[2][1]==x[2][2]
        Диагональ=x[O][O]==x[1][1]==x[2][2] or ei=x[O][2]==x[1][1]==x[2][O]
        for ei in ['X', 'O']:
            if ei == строка:
                return ei
        else:
            return '?'


print(Победитель([['O',' ','X'],
                  ['O','X',' '],
                  ['X',' ',' ']]))
```

Задание заключается в том, что в конечном итоге должен выдавать победителя, из ходя поля , которое нарисовано в команде print. Если победителя нет, то должен выдавать '?'.

Выдает ошибку:

> ```
> %Run kodu4.py
>   File "C:\Users\Ximaks\Desktop\kodu4.py", line 5
>     diagonaalis=x[O][O]==x[1][1]==x[2][2] or ei=x[O][2]==x[1][1]==x[2][O]
>                ^
> SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
> ```

Расскажите и если не сложно, подправьте код.
Большое спасибо

Comment: А вы уверены, что индексами должна быть буква "O"?

Comment: У вас присваивание вместо сравнения в этой строчке

Comment: И да, вложенный цикл с той же переменной...

Comment: Да, должно быть буква "O". В задание отдельная пометка, что не "0" , буква O.

Comment: Вероятно, эта пометка касалась содержимого поля, а не его индексов?

Answer (score 1):

Советую воспользоваться какой-нибудь `IDE`, например `PyCharm` (на скриншоте). На многие ошибки `IDE` сможет указать еще до выполнения кода.

И не стоит пренебрегать форматированием кода.

Если приглядеться к скриншоту и к месту, где `IDE` не понравилось можно увидеть опечатку: `or ei = x[O][2] == x[1][1] == x[2][O]`

Правильно должно быть: `or ei == x[O][2] == x[1][1] == x[2][O]`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Проверкой и исправлением ошибок не делал, только добавил переменную `O`, которая неизвестно откуда взялась вместо `0`, чтобы убрать предупреждения IDE в коде